# Annotate a Class with many properties using flow?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have a class with many member properties. All this duplication seems ridiculous. Is there a less verbose way to annotate it?

```
type Args = {
  name: string,
  flush_timeout: number,
  close_timeout: number,
  slab_threshold: number,
  slab_fanout: number,
  max_writers: number,
  min_time: EpochObj,
  max_time: EpochObj,
  size: number,
  packet_support: boolean,
  compression: string,
  path: string
}

export default class Space {
  name: string
  flush_timeout: number
  close_timeout: number
  slab_threshold: number
  slab_fanout: number
  max_writers: number
  min_time: EpochObj
  max_time: EpochObj
  size: number
  packet_support: boolean
  compression: string
  path: string

  constructor(args: Args) {
    this.name = args.name
    this.flush_timeout = args.flush_timeout
    this.close_timeout = args.close_timeout
    this.slab_threshold = args.slab_threshold
    this.slab_fanout = args.slab_fanout
    this.max_writers = args.max_writers
    this.min_time = args.min_time
    this.max_time = args.max_time
    this.size = args.size
    this.packet_support = args.packet_support
    this.compression = args.compression
    this.path = args.path
  }
}
```

Comment: SO knew it, your post is really unclear. Please clarify what exactly are you asking for help. Just code and its title will not be enough to answer it.

Comment: My question is is there a less verbose way to annotate a Javascript class using flow-type. I think my question is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a **hack**, that `$ReadOnly<Space>` will represent `Space` instance members:

```
export default class Space {
  name: string
  flush_timeout: number
  ...

  constructor(args: $ReadOnly<Space>) {
    this.name = args.name
    this.flush_timeout = args.flush_timeout
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: This looked promising, but Flow throws errors when instantiating that class. See this example: https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBjGBDAzrsABQFMAnXOAOzAG9UwxLsBbYgLjFwBdSBLSgOboGGKt1IBXDFzikAFNlIDcHEuSoBKWvQZguAC164AdE1ZgAvGEXLTLYjoC+qZ5jFdOlxsSRqKlORozdjAAIgApe1xQxw0gA

Comment: @jkerr838, good point. With $ReadOnly [it seems to work](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBjGBDAzrsABQFMAnXOAOzAG9UwxLsBbYgLjFwBdSBLSgOboGGKt1IBXDFzikAFNlIDcHACQAlYtgAmAeUowAngB4S5KgD4AlLXoMwXABa9cAOiaswAXjCLl7lmI7AF9UUMwxLk5vRmIkMwpKORoPdjAAci5ibnTgqyA)

Answer (score 0):

Class in flow is [nominally typed](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/nominal-structural/#toc-nominal-typing) but we can convert it to Structural typing by using `type $NominalToStruct<T: {}> = $Exact<$ReadOnly<T>>;`

```
class A {
  name: string;
}

// expect error due to nominal types
const a: A = {name: 'Bob'};

// Correct
const a2: $NominalToStruct<A> = {name: 'Bob'};
```

So we can say that `Space` constructor accept Space-like structure.

```
export default class Space {
  name: string
  flush_timeout: number
  close_timeout: number

  constructor(args: $NominalToStruct<Space>) {
    this.name = args.name
    this.flush_timeout = args.flush_timeout
    this.close_timeout = args.close_timeout
  }
}

new Space({name: '', flush_timeout: 1, close_timeout: 2})
```

If our class have some extra fields or methods - we can move that construction to Parent class and use `super`

```
class SpaceChild extends Space {
  extraField: 1;

  constructor(args: $NominalToStruct<Space>){
    super(args);
  }

  extraMethod(){}
}
```

Comment: This would be the answer to my problem but I just plugged it in in TryFlow and get an error about $NominalToStruct not able to resolve. https://flow.org/try/#0KYDwDg9gTgLgBAE2AMwIYFcA28DGnUDOBcAymKjsHAN4BQccAdqgLbABccBMUAlowHN6cZJnQEAFgH0YvNhHQxOjdCwBGwKMLwQCwGXOAKlTVRq3aIjblHQ4Y0ABSooAgpwAkAOQgt+qTAAVCBIeOxgAHjIKYAA+AEoaYQYYCV4CADpmNjgAXjgXNyzWYGS4VPSM0XFpWXlFPILXTOrJA3qYMorMnT12owb8wp7MXX06gc6GAF9aWdpGYAB3UnJKR2psjjgAch2AGhExNonjTgBGQ97xwzO4ACZp+KA I also searched the docs for it and found nothing. Maybe it was taken out of the most recent version of flow?

Comment: It is a custom type that i described at the start: `type $NominalToStruct<T: {}> = $Exact<$ReadOnly<T>>;`